# Entender instanciacao de classes

Tags: c#

Tenho uma dúvida e gostaria de entender melhor como funciona a instanciação de classes. Mais especificamente a forma mais adequada de fazer(se existir) e os impactos de fazer da forma errada.

Supondo esses dois cenários, qual devo utilizar e Porque?

Cenário 1: Instanciando fora dos métodos.

```
public class PerfilController : Controller
{
    PerfilDTO viewDTO = new PerfilDTO();
    Perfil perfilNEG= new Perfil();
    Recurso recursoNEG = new Recurso();

    public ActionResult Cadastro()
    {
        viewDTO.ListaPerfis = perfilNEG.ObterPerfis();
        viewDTO.ListaRecursos = recursoNEG.ObterRecursos();

        return View(viewDTO);
    }      

    public ActionResult Listagem()
    {
        viewDTO.ListaPerfis = perfilNEG.ObterPerfis();
        viewDTO.ListaRecursos = recursoNEG.ObterRecursos();

        return View(viewDTO);
    }      
}
```

Cenário 2: Instanciando dentro dos métodos

```
public class PerfilController : Controller
{      
    public ActionResult Cadastro()
    {
        PerfilDTO viewDTO = new PerfilDTO();
        Perfil perfilNEG= new Perfil();
        Recurso recursoNEG = new Recurso();

        viewDTO.ListaPerfis = perfilNEG.ObterPerfis();
        viewDTO.ListaRecursos = recursoNEG.ObterRecursos();

        return View(viewDTO);
    }      

    public ActionResult Listagem()
    {
        PerfilDTO viewDTO = new PerfilDTO();
        Perfil perfilNEG= new Perfil();
        Recurso recursoNEG = new Recurso();

        viewDTO.ListaPerfis = perfilNEG.ObterPerfis();
        viewDTO.ListaRecursos = recursoNEG.ObterRecursos();

        return View(viewDTO);
    }      
}
```

OBS: Se houver outra forma diferente e melhor também podem me alertar.

Comment: Se você declara a propridade dentro do método, ela só existe no método. Se declara fora, ela pertence à instância e é visível em todos os métodos.

Comment: Sim, eu prefiro colocar fora, mas como não entendo muito bem ainda fiquei com medo disso ser ruim de alguma forma. Não há problema então de iniciar fora dos métodos então?

Comment: Olha, não sou especialista em C#, mas seria legal declarar a visibilidade dessas propriedades (private, public, etc). Assim sem declarar devem ser todas implicitamente public.

Comment: Amigo, também não sou nenhum especialista, mas recomendo pesquisar sobre "Lazy Initialization", ou "Initialization on Demand", onde você só cria a instância do objeto realmente quando for utilizar, e esse padrão também implementa o Padrão "Singleton". Talvez a noite se ninguém tiver elaborado um resposta a respeito disso eu post uma. Mas recomendo ler sobre esse assunto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao meu ver:

Instanciando da primeira forma, ao você criar o objeto `PerfilController` também serão criados mais 3 objetos em memória (`PerfilDTO`, `Perfil` e `Recurso`) mesmo se eles nunca forem usados.

Instanciando da segunda forma, os 3 objetos mencionados serão criados apenas quando os métodos forem chamados, ou seja, quando realmente for necessário. A desvantagem é que você precisa instanciar em cada método (repetição de código) e os objetos serão criados diversas vezes em memória conforme o número de chamadas ao método.

O que você poderia fazer (isso que vou falar é passível de análise) é se utilizar do padrão de projetos *[Singleton](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton)*, que garante apenas uma instância de determinado objeto. Exemplo:

```
private ClasseExemplo getObjetoExemplo() {
    if (objetoExemplo == null) {
        objetoExemplo = new ClasseExemplo();
    }
    return objetoExemplo;
}
```

E onde for necessário, bastaria usar esse método:

```
objeto.objetoExemplo = getObjetoExemplo():
```

Assim estaria garantido que o objeto seria instanciado apenas quando necessário e somente uma vez.

Quis dar minha contribuição conforme aquilo que eu entendo, quem sabe outras pessoas expliquem de forma mais ampla e didática que eu.

Comment: Meu projeto é bem pequeno. Nesse caso instanciar fora dos métodos não causará tanto impacto de memória. Estou certo? Ou digamos que em um looping de acesso ao controller isso pode ser prejudicial?

Comment: Eu não vejo que possa ser prejudicial, ainda mais sendo um sistema pequeno, mas como nós seres humanos falhos não conseguimos prever todas situações que podem ocorrer em um sistema, eu te recomendo a fazer da melhor forma possível, independente de ser um sistema pequeno ou não (não estou afirmando que a minha resposta seja a melhor forma). Conselho (que serve também pra mim): quando for desenvolver um sistema, mesmo pequeno, sempre preocupe-se com escalabilidade, manutenibilidade e desempenho.

Comment: Certo, estou tentando fazer isso, por isso vim buscar a melhor alternativa com as opiniões daqui! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Completando a correta resposta de Electus: Se você declara os objetos no "topo" da classe, toda vez que essa classe for instanciada esse objetos também serão criados, mesmo que não sejam necessários e isso pode causar problemas de desempenho. Cada caso é um caso, mas procure analisar bem onde inicializa os objetos, para ter certeza que estão dentro do escopo correto (dentro do método, dentro da classe) e ganhar em desempenho e também organização do seu código.
Mesmo sendo uma aplicação pequena um dia ela pode vir a ser grande e esses erros iniciais pode lhe causar problemas lá na frente.

Answer (score 2):

**Existe outra forma diferente e melhor.**

Recomendo você utilizar do padrão [**Repository**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) para recuperar as informações necessárias para o seu *Controller*.

**Por que utilizá-lo nessa situação?**

Com esse padrão você pode evitar essa duplicação de códigos para instanciar seus objetos, melhorar a manutenção do código, entre outros benefícios como a realização de testes.

**Qual o problema em ficar criando essas instâncias no Controller?**

Não é responsabilidade do seu *Controller* instanciar objetos como PerfilDTO, Perfil e Recurso. É responsabilidade do Controller buscar dados do Model e encaminhar a View relacionada para exibição desses dados.

Comment: Acredito que se você desse um exemplo de como utilizar esse padrão ficaria mais claro.